# Using SUMPRODUCT with Value Manipulation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count cells in a column that contain either numbers between `0000` and `2400` or `"TBD"`. The actual column entries contain numbers, "ddmmm" dates, and text in no particular order. The entire column is force formatted into text.

Without including any true text entries, the following formula works:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(VALUE(H:H)>0)*--(VALUE(H:H)<2401))`

But once I start throwing text entries in, VALUE obviously #VALUE!'s out. I'm having trouble getting it to work in a range that throws errors for the VALUE function.

Tl;dr: I need to count entries in a text-formatted column that contain numbers 0000-2400 or the text "TBD". I've hit a wall with entries that can't be converted with VALUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Array Formula

```
=SUM(IFERROR((--H:H>0)*(--H:H<2401),0)+(H:H="TBD"))
```

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Boom, nice, have not seen SUM with IFERROR inside CSE, very cool.

Comment: @BigBen the `IFERROR` forces the use of CSE even with SUMPRODUCT, which why I use `SUM` as I am not saving the CSE entry and it is less typing.

Comment: How do you handle the column being forced as text formatting and having other text entries other than TBD that don't need to be counted?

Comment: If it is a number stored as text the `--` will turn it to a number or it will cause an error which the IFERROR handles. Then it counts the cells with TBD

Answer (score 0):

So, VALUE("0000") gives you 0 and VALUE("2400") gives you 2400, so that means that those will work as you expect. The issue is probably when you run into TBD or any other value.

You need to use an IF statement to catch it before it evaluates VALUE() and errors out.

```
=IF(ISERR(VALUE(<cell>)),IF(<cell>="TBD",<do TBD stuff here>,<entry is not a date or TBD>),SUMPRODUCT(...))
```

Little easier to read in "classic" if statement format:

```
IF (VALUE(<cell>) = ERR)
{
    IF (<cell> = "TBD")
    {
        <do TBD stuff here>
    }ELSE{
        <entry is not a date or TBD>
    }
}ELSE{
    SUMPRODUCT(...)
}
```

Comment: Right, but there are other text entries other than TBD that need to be filtered out.

Comment: @tony971. Your question was `Tl;dr: I need to count entries in a text-formatted column that contain numbers 0000-2400 or the text "TBD"`. That is the answer I provided. The other text entries that are not "TBD" are handled in the `<entry is not a date or TBD>` else statement. You can do whatever you want here. If you want it to be blank use `" "`. If you want to do display something else, type it there.